# Pandas droping rows based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames

```
A = pd.DataFrame(
    [["abc@gmail.com","4311","3000","STR_1","1384"],
     ["abc@gmail.com","4311","3000","STR_2","1440"  ],
     ["xyz@gmail.com","4311","3000","STR_3","1300"  ],
     ["pqr@gmail.com","4311","3000","STR_3","1300"  ]],
    columns=["EMAIL",   "PRODUCT_ID",   "POST_CODE",    "STORE_NAME",   "STORE_ID"],
)
```

[image]

```
B = pd.DataFrame(
    [["abc@gmail.com","4311","3000","STR_1","1384"],
     ["xyz@gmail.com","4311","3000","STR_3","1300"  ],],
    columns=["EMAIL",   "PRODUCT_ID",   "POST_CODE",    "STORE_NAME",   "STORE_ID"],
)
```

[image]

Now I need to remove records from dataframe A that have the same EMAIL, PRODUCT_ID, and **POST_CODE** as data frame B. So the expected output is

[image]

I tried using drop duplicates like:

```
pd.concat([A, B]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

But this cannot drop rows based on a custom column which is the POST_CODE in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this contains the following elements:

1. pandas set_index() function.
2. pandas  isin() function.

First we will set the index in the two dataframes to be "EMAIL", "PRODUCT_ID", "POST_CODE" then we can use these indexing to filter the dataframes using isin.

The code:

```
import pandas as pd

A = pd.DataFrame(
    [["abc@gmail.com","4311","3000","STR_1","1384"],
     ["abc@gmail.com","4311","3000","STR_2","1440"  ],
     ["xyz@gmail.com","4311","3000","STR_3","1300"  ],
     ["pqr@gmail.com","4311","3000","STR_3","1300"  ]],
    columns=["EMAIL",   "PRODUCT_ID",   "POST_CODE",    "STORE_NAME",   "STORE_ID"],
)

B = pd.DataFrame(
    [["abc@gmail.com","4311","3000","STR_1","1384"],
     ["xyz@gmail.com","4311","3000","STR_3","1300"  ],],
    columns=["EMAIL",   "PRODUCT_ID",   "POST_CODE",    "STORE_NAME",   "STORE_ID"],
)

i1 = A.set_index(["EMAIL", "PRODUCT_ID", "POST_CODE"]).index
i2 = B.set_index(["EMAIL", "PRODUCT_ID", "POST_CODE"]).index
result = A[~i1.isin(i2)]
```

Output:

```
     EMAIL         PRODUCT_ID    POST_CODE  STORE_NAME  STORE_ID
3   pqr@gmail.com    4311          3000       STR_3       1300
```

Answer (score 2):

use `subset` to select on the columns you want to filter out

```
pd.concat([A, B]).drop_duplicates(subset=["EMAIL",   "PRODUCT_ID",   "POST_CODE"], keep=False)
```

Comment: This solution doesn't give the desired output because it still leaves one of the duplicates causing abc@gmail.com , xyz@gmail.com and pqr@gmail.com to be the output and not only pqr@gmail.com. edit the answer add the argument keep=False to drop_duplicates and this will work perfectly :)

Comment: @RoseGod yes, you are right I missed that part